# Simple Obj-C Memory Management Question

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

This is from some sample code from a book

```
// On launch, create a basic window
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
 UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[HelloController alloc] init]];
 [window addSubview:nav.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

But a `release` is never called for `window` nor for `nav`.

1. Release should be called since `alloc` was called, right?
2. If #1 is right, then I would need to store a reference to each of these in an instance variable in order to release them in the `dealloc`?

Perhaps I'm wrong all around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, normally.

However; UIWindow is normally not released, nor is the root navigation controller, as, well, what's the point. They last for the duration of your application.

Also, get a newer book; we use Interface Builder for this stuff now.

Comment: +1 and thank you. Book says 2009, but they get to Interface Builder "later." I don't know if I'm convinced.